# I have got a problem about Liferay's 7 Configuration

Tags: java, liferay-7

I create configuration for my portlet, but when i press "save" the method @Activate/@Modified 's called twice, so it throws the excpetion because it try to create a Server that the Server was created first time.

```
@Activate
@Modified

protected void activate(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {

 if(VIMAPConfigurationUtil.enabled()) {

    if (_log.isInfoEnabled()) {
           _log.info("DBG SMTP initServer");
    }

    _nioSocketAcceptor = new NioSocketAcceptor();

    _nioSocketAcceptor.setReuseAddress(true);


       DefaultIoFilterChainBuilder chain = 
       _nioSocketAcceptor.getFilterChain();

    addSSLSupport(chain);


    chain.addLast("logger", new VIMAPLogger());


    chain.addLast("codec", new ProtocolCodecFilter(new 
            VIMAPCodeFactory(Charset.forName(StringPool.UTF8))));


    _nioSocketAcceptor.setHandler(new DefaultSMTPIoHandler());


    SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(
                VIMAPConfigurationUtil.smtpBindPort());

    _nioSocketAcceptor.bind(socketAddress);


    }else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: That method should be modified and called when deploying your bundle by Service Component. It should not be mapped to an action. Otherwise, could you explain more ? Is this a portlet code ? Did you try to do an action command for the "save" action ?

Comment: i haven't got interface, so the button save is for the configuration under "System Setting"-> "Other". i don't understand because the method was called twice instead of one.

Comment: Because the Component is activated based on configuration.

Comment: Well, either way, with `@Activate` *and* `@Modified` annotations on that method, you'll have to be prepared to a previous server already running (consider a configuration done again) and issue a controlled shutdown of that potentially existing server. If you're interested in the root cause of duplicate calls, separate @Activate and @Modified to separate methods and log when each is called and inspect their call stack.